# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode' Arduino and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, arduino

I need to read some numbers sent by an Arduino via the serial port and then insert these numbers into a MySQL table.

This is my code:

```
import mysql.connector, serial

ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyACM3', baudrate='9600')
ser.isOpen()
read_port = ser.readline()
print (read_port)
mysql_connection = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="optim_admin", passwd="marcopolo", database="optimbit_acces")
cursor = mysql_connection.cursor()
sql1 = "insert into check_in (card, checkin) values (%s, Now()); ", (read_port)
cursor.execute(sql1)
mysql_connection.close()
```

This is my error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin1/Documents/OptimAcces/db_service_connect.py", line 10, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql1, (str(read_port.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii', 'utf-8')), ))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 492, in execute
    stmt = operation.encode(self._connection.python_charset)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are entering wrong parameters syntax from your code. Try this:

```
 from time import gmtime, strftime

 date_time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
 sql1 = "insert into check_in (card, checkin) values (%s, %s)"
 args = read_port, date_time
 cursor.execute(sql1, args)
```

The Error message that you are facing is because your query has wrong number of parameters and has more brackets not correct closed.

See below the signature for cursor.execute:

```
Definition: cursor.execute(self, query, args=None)
     query -- string, query to execute on server
     args -- optional sequence or mapping, parameters to use with query
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: hi, thanks for the help, i've change my code but now i encounter this:

mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: 'now()' for column 'checkin' at row 1

Process finished with exit code 1

any ideea?

Comment: What's the datatype defined for checkin colum in database ? i supose it should be date time type. I think you have to include, import date time lib to your code. like

Comment: `from time import gmtime, strftime`
     `date_time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())`

Comment: @BogdanRadu : Please let me know if you've  solved this issue.

Comment: hi, i dont know if i answered to you. i solved the problem by switching to mariadb. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. I solved the problem by switching the database to MariaDb from MySql. Now it works fine.

Thank you for your help.